# Simulating live typing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to write a script that converts an input's current value (int) to words.

```
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'You must enter a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            }
            else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return false;
}


var input = $('#numbers'),
    label = $('.words'),
    converted = toWords(input.val());

input.bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    converted = toWords(this.value)
    setTimeout(function() {
        label.empty().text(converted);
    }, 1000);
});​
```

At this point, I am able to live type whatever I enter, but once I send it through the `toWords` function, it grabs the value of the input that was given when the page loaded.

In other words, it doesn't update the input field's value with my new number entered, which should then convert to words.

Any ideas? - http://jsfiddle.net/qTBxv/211/

Comment: You should indent your code. And I personally am not a fan of all the one-liners, but that's less "mandatory".

Comment: Yeah, it was some copy/paste for quick and dirty... That portion of the code was more or less irrelevant but I will format it next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to update the converted variable with the input's new value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    input.bind('keyup', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            converted = toWords(input.val());
            label.append(converted);
    }, 500);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qTBxv/214/

Comment: Thank you very much. +1 answer when it allows.

Answer (score 3):

Add a call to `toWords`, passing current input value in attached event as well.

```
input.bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    converted = toWords(this.value)
    setTimeout(function() {
        label.empty().text(converted);
    }, 1000);
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/qTBxv/217/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure to update `converted` every time the value changes (in this case, you're hooking into key events, so you can do it there). Like so:

```
var input = $('#numbers'),
    label = $('.words'),
    converted;

input.bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    converted = toWords(input.val());
    setTimeout(function() {
        label.empty().text(converted);
    }, 1000);
});​
```

That seemed to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest [angularJS](http://angularjs.org/) as your ultimate answer.